# Name of a function for button inside searchbar

Tags: ios, ios5, ios4, applescript

[image: ios searchbar option]

Hi everybody, does anyone know what the [a...] button function inside the searchbar is called within iOS?

I am looking for a tutorial on how to do this kind of function but already have difficulty naming the function itself to look for it.

Thank you very much!

Comment: what does it do? I'm very sure this is costum work. Either you do a subclass of the UISearchBar or you try to insert a button(don't know if it's possible.

Comment: It changes the behavior of the search query, i.e. performs LIKE "a%" or LIKE "%a".

Comment: Okay it's definitely costume. I think you need to create a costume UISearchBar with a Button inside or you try to lay the button over it. I'm sure there a several ways but unfortunately I'm not familiar with it. I hope someone will help you ;)

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200149/styling-the-cancel-button-in-a-uisearchbar

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be a custom search UI.

I would call it a wildcard search. Could also be referred to as "beginsWith" for the shown example, or "endsWith" for a different type of search.

For the search logic:
http://www.cocoanetics.com/2010/03/filtering-fun-with-predicates/

And for the UI:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISearchBar_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Thank you very much for those links. Could you describe or hint at how to build a subclass for the UI to accomodate buttons inside the search field? This seems quite hard to derive from just the UI reference.

Comment: Maybe you can look here for some inspiration: https://github.com/thermogl/TITokenField

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the iOS SDK does not include a prebuilt way of doing this, so you will have to build a custom control.
Use UITextField as the base and add your button as the leftView.

Check out this question: [Adding subviews to UITextField leftView property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2830112/adding-subviews-to-uitextfield-leftview-property)

I hope this helps.